# spark streaming multiple sockets sources

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am pretty new to Spark. For my project I need to combine data coming from different streams on different ports. To test that I did an exercise which aim is to print data coming from streams from different ports. Below you can see the code:

```
object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Seconds(2))
    val lines9 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    val lines8 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998)

    lines9.print()
    lines8.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Than I run those code and start nc -lk 9999 and nc -lk 9998. When I put anything on port 9999 I see the output on Spark- works fine. When I put anything on 9998 I don't see any output.

Could you please explain me why there is no output on 9998 and how should I implement this to combine those two streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find an answer for my problem. It is so simple that I feel silly to post it here.

The problem was in executing application. I was doing it by:
./spark-submit --class hello  
while proper way to do this was:
./spark-submit --class hello --master local[2]

Anyway, thanks guys for contribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can this ( `Dstream1.union(Dstream2)` ) approch to combine your Dstreams. It will return one new Dstream.

Comment: kaushal, this will create one stream from two and my aim is to do custom filtering on every stream and than join them together.

Answer (score -1):

// Perfectly working multi socket spark streaming example with single streaming context.
// with check point on local directory

```
import org.apache.spark._

import org.apache.spark.streaming._

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

var dir_path_opp="file:///Users/keeratjohar2305/Downloads/59e8f3c42ef0ee849a77-ef2360e85067356b16ebd3af2689db720a47963d/SIKANDRABAD_CP_TEST"
```

// Create a local StreamingContext with batch interval of 3 second  FOR THE FIRST TIME

```
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {


  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NetworkWordCount").setMaster("local[*]")

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))   // new context

  val sc = ssc.sparkContext    // created just to reduce logging

  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  ssc.checkpoint(dir_path_opp) 

  ssc

  }
```

// CREATE STREAM CONTEXT IF NOT EXIST IN THE checkpoint

```
val sscc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(dir_path_opp, ()=>functionToCreateContext())
```

//UpdateByKey to Maintain state

```
 def updatefunc(v: Seq[Int], rc: Option[Int]) = {

     val nc = v.sum + rc.getOrElse(0)

     new Some(nc)

  }
```

// First stream opened

```
val lines = sscc.socketTextStream("localhost",9999)

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

var tolcnt= wordCounts.updateStateByKey(updatefunc _)

tolcnt.print()
```

// Second stream opened

```
val lines1 = sscc.socketTextStream("localhost",6666)

val words1 = lines1.flatMap(_.split(" "))

val wordCounts1 = words1.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCounts1.print()


sscc.start()

sscc.awaitTermination()    // add it if you want to program to run infinitaly.
```